# PHP error while looping through the list

Tags: php

I am trying to loop through the list of strings stored in a configuration file.

bar.txt (config file):

```
arr = array("one", "two", "three");
```

bar.php (main file):

```
<?php
$filename = "/home/test/bar.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

echo $contents;

foreach ($arr as $value) {

echo $value;

}

fclose($handle);

?>
```

output: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/test/bar.php on line 8`

Comment: In your config, is it arr = or is it $arr = ?

Comment: Does the text file actually have *PHP code* in it?  That's probably not going to work the way you think it does.  The loop doesn't work because you never define `$arr`.  The text file should contain the data, the PHP file should contain the code which uses the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an easier way to do this would be like this:

First of all, correct `arr` to `$arr` in your file, then, add  tags on it. Change extension to `bar.php` if you want (but you may keep txt extension if you need.).

Then, try to use include instead of fread:

```
<?php
include "/home/test/bar.php";

foreach ($arr as $value) {

    echo $value;

}
```

Comment: Same comment applies in regards to what I left under Vladimir's answer.

Comment: I am getting output as: onetwothree. Can I get in separate lines?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Fred. I didn't knew it parse txt too (if have the <?php).

Comment: Rio, you may concatenate an space or whatever you want in your echo: echo $value . " "; or echo $value . "<br/>";

Comment: I want to get one, two and three in separate lines. How do I get it?

Comment: if you're using PHP cli (console), use: echo $value . "\n"; if you're executing it in browser, try: echo $value . "<br/>";

Answer (score 1):

In bar.txt `arr` should be `$arr`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your array within php tags and use require_once ( recommended ) to include it:

> bar.php

```
<?php $arr = array("one", "two", "three"); ?>
```

> Mainscript.php

```
<?php
    require_once( "bar.php" );
    foreach ($arr as $value) 
    {
    echo $value;
    echo '<br />';

    }
?>
```

Comment: `Bar.php` - it could also be a `.txt` file, just as long as the file does contain an opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: I am getting output as: onetwothree. Can I get output in separate lines?

Comment: @VladimirRamik `\n` is only good when writing to files or viewed in HTML source. For a new line for onscreen viewing, OP needs to use `<br>` tag. Best to use `echo $value . "<br>\n";`

Comment: Forgot we were outputting to a browser. Fixed.

Comment: `echo $value . "<br>\n";` will produce clean HTML, should the OP decide to use it with HTML formatting, such as table tags. I always use both `<br>` and `\n` in all output.

Comment: This is what I did: echo $value . "\n";